# Specialize EJB in JBoss

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, jboss7.x, cdi

I asked this a while ago within a Jboss 4.2.3 (JavaEE 5) context and got the answer to try Spring for configuration, but I'd rather not add another framework when it isn't necessary.

Now with JavaEE 6 and 7 out I have the feeling that there's a simpler solution for my problem. However I wasn't lucky searching yet so if you can get me on the right track, I'd really appreciate your help.

Here's the problem:

Suppose we have an EJB interface `IEjb` and a library that provides an implentation `EjbA` of that interface. There are several other libraries which provide further EJBs and a couple of those contain `@EJB IEjb ref`, i.e. they need a reference to en EJB which exposes interface `IEjb`.

Now, there is the need to *completely* replace `EjbA` with an alternate implementation `EjbB`, i.e. `EjbA` should *never* be using in the entire application.

There are a few options that we can't use or which would require rather large changes:

- "don't deploy the library containing `EjbA`": this is not possible, since there are other EJBs which are needed
- "extract `EjbA` from the lib": that would require rather large changes in our libraries and the applications that use them
- "implement `EjbA` as a non-EJB, subclass it when needed and make the subclass an EJB": the same reasons as above apply, this would require rather large changes
- "delete `EjbA`": there are other applications which need to use it, it's currently just one application which should use a replacement instead.

So there are a few ways that I could think of:

- tell the server not to deploy `EjbA` so that the only implementation of `IEjb` would be `EjbB` and dependency injection would be fine
- tell dependency injection to always use `EjbB` when an instance of `IEjb` is required (something like CDI's `@Specializes` but for EJBs - possible in JavaEE 7?)

Any ideas on this? Is this possible (I have the feeling that yes) and if so, how?

A note on the environment: we're currently running on JBoss 7.2.0, but if this would only be possible using Wildfly, this might be an option (although we'd prefer not to be forced to update already).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of ideas:

- delete EjbA if it mustn't be used anyway
- remove the EJB annotations
- use @Inject to inject local EJBs (recommended anyway). I think CDI lets you specify a default implementation, AFAIK.

Comment: Deleting `EjbA` isn't an option since it should only be replaced in a single application, others need to use it. Removing the annotations is also not an option as described above. However, I like the idea of using `@Inject` and will try that as this should enable us to use `@Specializes`, at least with a newer WELD version.

Comment: +1 to use @Inject instead of @EJB to inject @EJB. With this approach you get the best of the 2 worlds EJB+CDI. If you do that there's no problem to use CDI `@Alternative` or `@Specializes`

Answer (score 1):

A littlebit late, but remember: EJB supports transactions, where as CDI-Beans not. But you could wrap the injection of an EJB in a corresponding CDI-bean, that proxies all methods of the EJB. To get enother EJB you'll write a @Specializes-CDI for it. Example (just to show, what I mean).

The Baseimplementation looks like this:

```
@Stateless // or whatever
class BaseEjb {
    public void doSomeMagic() {...}
}

@Named
class BaseCdi {
    @EJB
    private BaseEjb ejb;
    public void doSomeMagic() { ejb.doSomeMagic(); }
}
```

The customisation works like this:

```
@Stateless // or whatever
class SpecializedEjb extends BaseEjb {...}

@Specializes
class SpecializedCdi extends BaseCdi {
    @EJB
    private SpecializedEjb ejb;
    public void doSomeMagic() { ejb.doSomeMagic(); }
}
```

Comment: Hey, yes with CDI we were able to just do something like that. Basically EJBs _are_ CDI beans and thus support specialization out of the box. We'd just need to replace `@EJB` (which provides a few features we rarely used anyways) with `@Inject` (which would be the preferred way for injection anyways). We've faced a problem with JBoss 7.2 though since we used a custom interceptor and that interferred with available Weld version's EJB resolution. In Wildfly (at least 10.0 which we're using) it works perfectly.

Comment: Thanks for feedback!